# Using function pointers to display return value of function

Tags: c++, function-pointers, virtual-functions

I am required to use function pointers to output the return value of the first virtual function inside a class. The function is located in a virtual table and I am trying to return the value of this function but I keep getting the address getting returned to me instead of the actual value that I want. I know I'm at the right place because when I was outputting values during debugging, I was printing the value of `(output[0][0])();` it was giving me the correct value. However when I am running the program in the terminal window I can't get it to give me the same value. Instead I'm getting an address value. This is my current code.

```
#include <cstdio>

class X
{
private:
    int v_one;
    int v_two;
    virtual int adder()
    {
        return v_one/v_two;
    }
public:
    X(){
        v_one = 15;
        v_two = 3;
    }
};

int getValue(void* x){
    int a;
    int *y = static_cast<int*>(x);
    int (***output)();
    output = (int (***)())(&y[0]);
    a = (output[0][0])();
    return a;
}

int main(){
    X x;
    printf("%d\n", getValue(&x));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: please provide an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @tobi303 i added the main function to display the value I'm trying to get.

Comment: thats not an mcve. What is `X` ?

Comment: Interesting gag. Any Language Lawyers want to comment on the viability and portability of this idea? I don't think the standard specifies exactly where the v-table goes.

Comment: Or even if there is one, now that I think about it.

Comment: @user4581301 I am quite ignorant when it comes to the standard, but I would not be surprised if it doesnt mention vtables at all

Comment: @tobi303 i apologize. I thought I included the class X in my edit.

Comment: Why are you passing `x` as a `void*`, type-casting it to `int*`, and using pointer arithmetic to reach the virtual `adder()` method?  This code is very dangerous and not portable.  Why can't you just pass `x` as an `X*` pointer and call `adder()` normally?

Comment: The language has no concept of "virtual table" and therefore no concept to "first virtual function (in that table)". This question only makes sense as a hack tailored to some specific implementation.

Comment: @tobi303 I was assuming that when there is a virtual function involved, that they are stored within a virtual table. I was referencing this wiki article for help. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table

Comment: @xjaysteeze: That is an implementation detail of the compiler, not dictated by the standard. *Most* compilers will use a VMT, but that is not required, and the details of the VMT layout are compiler-specific (except when COM is involved, since a COM object's VMT is part of the COM ABI for binary compatibility across compilers).

Comment: @RemyLebeau it was a pointer arithmetic exercise given to us to help us understand.

Comment: Thanks @AnT . Xjay, by the time an optimizing compiler is done, all bets are off. Anything it sees as waste is likely to be gone--and this could include a trivial vtable.

Comment: @xjaysteeze: "Virtual method table" is a popular practical approach to implementing the virtual function behavior required by C++ language. But such table and its format is an internal detail of specific implementation. In addition to that the OP is attempting to call a member function through an ordinary function pointer, which is also a hack in itself.

Comment: @tobi303 Why does `X` not need a vtable? It has a virtual function. As for what you're doing, it's very dangerous. I'm not even sure what you mean by the return value of that function; it returns different things depending on the `X` instance it's attached to; without calling it properly, how do you expect to get the value?

Comment: @NirFriedman essentially when I am running the program I want to be able to display the value of one/two. I guess my real question would now be how to call it properly to get the value.

Comment: @tobi I don't think it works that way; when you take this code and compile it into a .o file, it will have an entry in the symbol table for the class `X`. This in principle can be linked to other pieces of code, which can use `X` in various ways including those where the vtable is necessary. And in fact, printing sizeof X on my compiler (clang37) shows it to be 16 bytes: 4 x 2 = 8 bytes for two integers, + 8 for the vtable pointer.

Comment: @NirFriedman hm ok, that makes sense. I better delete my comments, others might think that I know what I am talking about ;)

Comment: @xjaysteeze I can only guess, these are all implementation dependent details. My best guess is that once you get the proper pointer, you will need to cast it to a function pointer with signature `(int)(*)(X*)`, and then call it with an instance of `X`.

Comment: `output = (int (***)())(&y[0]);` is the same as `output = (int (***)())x;`.  Not sure what effect you think `y` is having in there.

Comment: @Nir Friedman: Unlikely to work. Many (most? all?) implementations give special treatment to the hidden `this` parameter, like always using the same CPU register to pass `this` (e.g. `rcx` on x86). Regular parameters will not necessarily be placed into that CPU register, which will break the whole thing.

Comment: @AnT how would the 'this' pointer work in this situation?

Comment: Sort of off-topic: A bit of reading on function pointers vs method pointers and how to use both: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members

Comment: @tobi303: It does not. The standard does not mention any implementing details. It only specifies results not how to achieve them.

Comment: All of this is completely illegal by the standard. You have a non conformant program and all you are likely to get is undefined behavior. The only legal way to get a method pointer is to ask the compiler. This will give you an error because it is private but a member function can return the address of any member function.

Comment: @xjaysteeze off topic, but how long have you been learning C++? As you can see, your instructor or whatever has really tossed you into the deep end here. You've been tasked with doing something that violates all that is holy, any hack solution won't necessarily work on both your and the instructor's compilers (making this an expletive deleted to mark), and requires knowledge of how method calls, particularly the hidden `this` parameter, work. This is a pretty nasty assignment, and I don't quite grasp what it is supposed to teach.

Comment: @user4581301 i've been learning for about a semester now. this assignment was just a way to get us familiar with pointers and such.

Comment: `this assignment was just a way to get us familiar with pointers and such` then you are misinterpreting the instructions of your assignment. You should have started with the exact wording. What you are trying to do is completely none sensical.

Comment: @xjaysteeze Credit to the teacher for trying something original--usually basic pointer use is taught with, "Implement a Linked List..."--but this lesson also teaches a lot of bad behaviour. If there are other assignment options, look into them instead. You'll learn more useful stuff than this hackery. If you have to hand in hackery for marks, take the marks and run. This problem can be, take this wording very loosely, "solved" in about 3 lines of language abuse that you can't count on. I think the big take-away here is can you do this? Maybe. Should you? no.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to get the address of a function is to ask the compiler.
Because `adder` is private you can't get this externally but you can get another public method return the address.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>

class X;
typedef int (X::*MFP)();
class X
{
private:
    int v_one;
    int v_two;
    virtual int adder()
    {
        return v_one/v_two;
    }
public:
    X(){
        v_one = 15;
        v_two = 3;
    }
    static MFP getAddr()
    {
        return &X::adder;
    }
};

int main()
{
    MFP  action = X::getAddr();
    X   a;
    std::cout << (a.*action)() << "\n";
}
```

Then you can call member functions using the `.*` or `->*` operators (but these still need a valid object to work).

There is just so much wrong with your get function.

```
int getValue(void* x){
    int a;
    // This cast is illegal.
    int *y = static_cast<int*>(x);

    // This is a function pointer.
    // A method pointer is a completely different animal.
    // The standard does not even guarantee a method pointer will fit
    // inside a function pointer value (if you are using virtual tables
    // it will absolutely not fit).
    int (***output)();

    // Yep this is meaningless.
    output = (int (***)())(&y[0]);

    // This is not how you call a method via a pointer.
    // Where do you think the `this` parameter is set up?
    a = (output[0][0])();

    return a;
}
```

### Function Vs Method Ptr

```
int (X::*method)()  = nullptr;
int (*function)()   = nullptr;

std::cout << sizeof(method) << "   :   " << sizeof(function) << "\n";

Results in:
===========
16   :   8
```